# I am getting wrong output in python

Tags: python, dictionary, unordered-map

Python dictionary is a collection which is unordered, changeable and indexed. No duplicate members.But when I run the code below, I see surprisingly wrong output (ordered tuples), it should be unordered. What's the problem with the code ?

```
my_dict = {}
my_dict['a'] = 1
my_dict['b'] = 2
my_dict['c'] = 3
my_dict['d'] = 4
my_dict['e'] = 5
my_dict['f'] = 6
my_dict['g'] = 7
my_dict['h'] = 8
my_dict['i'] = 9
for k, v in my_dict.items():
    print(k, v)
```

Comment: You are using python 2-python 3.5.

Comment: What exactly is your concern here? Just because you can't always rely on a dict being unordered does not mean it may never be so. Furthermore, the output is not wrong. And in Python 3.5 it's unsorted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In CPython 3.6 and (any) Python 3.7, dictionaries [remember their key insertion order](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-dev/2017-December/151283.html) and calls to `dict.keys`, `dict.values` and `dict.items` will reflect that order.

Additionally, "ordered by coincidence" is contained in the set of all arbitrary orderings you could get when printing in earlier implementations. :)

Comment: what do you mean by "ordered by coincidence" please explain a bit further

Comment: @sumon It means exactly that: The output might be ordered purely coincidental.

Comment: @sumon In the past, the language specification did not enforce the order of items `dict.items` produces - but that does not mean that getting a, b, c, ... by coincidence is impossible.

Comment: how can i get my expected output (unordered from ) of a dictionary?

Comment: @sumon that question does make no sense to me at all, sorry. Are you trying to use a dictionary for shuffling?

Comment: I want to mean that the definition says that Python dictionary is a collection which is unordered, but i see it's not unordered but ordered.

Comment: @sumon Yes, my answer explained to you what "unordered" means in this context. I can't say it any better.

Comment: You means that it's a coincidence? I may change with different keys, values?but i tried many other type of key value they all surprisingly give same ordered output not unordered

Comment: @sumon Read the first part of my answer. If you are using CPython 3.6 or any Python3.7 version, then you will get the `items` in the order in which you have put in the keys. If you are using another version of Python, yes, then it's a coincidence (for which the hashing algorithm is responsible).

Comment: Thanks a lot @timgeb sir for helping me to understand that topic